# Which flag I should for getting existing activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, flags

In my app 
Normal app lunches Activity1.
I am sharing file in Activity2.

How do I achieve following 
Activity1(normal launch app) -> Activity2 (Share file) -> Activity1 (By some button click) -> Activity2 (on back press) -> Exist app (on back press and not show Activity1)

Which flags I should use when I launch Activity1 from Activity2? And what should be launchMode for Activity1 and Activity1 in Manifest file?

Comment: lunchMode are not going to help here. If your steps are correct as written in question, you are breaking the back-press behaviour. In last you are showing Activity2 while pressing back from activity1, this is not a default behaviour or can not achieved by any launchMode. You need to launch Activity2 on backpress of Activity1, after checking if stack have no entry.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have two separate *App_1* and *App_2*, *Activity_1* belongs to *App_1* *Activity_2* to another. So, then

- Make that *Activity_2* direct accessible by Activity_2 app's Manifest

  ```
  <activity
      android:name=".Activity2">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="launch.Activity2.from.Activity1" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  ```
- Open *Activity_2* from *Activity_1* by

  ```
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setAction("launch.Activity2.from.Activity1");
      startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE);
  ```
- Once sharing finished or press the back button from Activity_2, then set result/flag to get it back in the *Activity_1*.

  ```
  setResult(RESULT_OK);//or RESULT_CANCELED based on action
  finish();
  ```
- So that will take you back to *Activity_1* and you can check the result/flag from `onActivityResult` (Also can send back data using `Intent` there)

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if (requestCode == YOUR_REQUEST_CODE) {
          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
              //TODO your logic
          }
      }
  }
  ```